# How to run a function each time I hit enter in the Python shell

Tags: python, automated-tests, read-eval-print-loop

I sometimes write small functions at the interactive shell.

They very rarely are correct the first time, so I spend a lot of time running the versions of my function on the same testset to verify correctness.

```
>>> def test_foo():
        print( foo(4) == 5 )
        print( foo(8) == 9 )
>>> def foo(x): return x + 1
>>> test_foo()
True
True
```

But `foo` may be more complicated and I may need 5 or more rewritings to get it to pass my tests, as running the suite manually is boring, I need something like this:

```
>>> def test_foo():
        print( foo(4) == 5 )
        print( foo(8) == 9 )
>>> :SET_ON_EXECUTION test_foo
```

And now each time I rewrite my `foo` function and send it to definition the test will be run too.

#### Some research

- Searching Google gives no useful answer.
- In the shell `python -h` does not tell me how to do this.
- Neither does `%quickref` in  `'ipython`, `.

Comment: Would you mind pressing the up arrow a few times, or control-R followed by a few characters, then tab and enter?

Comment: Alternatively, you can just quickly assign `f = test_foo`, which saves you about 8 characters. Now it's just `f()` at the prompt.

Comment: @Evert that is what I am currently doing, an automation would be very nice

Comment: A cell in the Jupyter (web) notebook is just a matter of (I think) alt-enter to execute the current cell. Edit the cell, alt-enter, edit, alt-enter etc. It's the closest to what I can think of. There are probably a few IDEs out there that have a similar behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You could edit your code in an editor and run your tests in a terminal using a file watcher, resulting in your tests being run every time you save the code or test files.

For information on how to run a command whenever a file changes (file watcher), see the answers on this question: https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes

Comment: Could you please give a bit more hints? Do you mean splitting the screen in half and when keeping the code in a file and the tests in the other? Isn't this similar to `doctest` just a less user-friendly?

Comment: I mean having an editor and a terminal open both at the same time on the screen. In the editor you would edit your code or your tests. In the terminal you would set up a file watcher that runs your tests whenever either the test file or your code file changes.
What OS are you using? Each OS has its own technology for file watching.

Comment: Interesting, I use Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend using [Jupyter notebooks](http://jupyter.org/) (previously known as IPython) for this. It allows you to create a 'cell' containing code which you can re-execute with `Ctrl-Enter` key combination.

For example in your case you could put the function definition and the execution in the same cell and then easily re-execute it as you edit.

[image: Jupyter notebook interface]

In this way you can gradually build up your code, fixing and developing a single function at a time.

As you already have IPython installed you should be able to get up and running with:

```
$ pip install jupyter
$ jupyter notebook
```

It will launch in your browser. Create a new notebook by clicking 'New' in the upper-right and selecting one of the Python kernels under 'Notebooks'.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `ipython`, you can just create a `whatever.py` file containing the code you want to run on startup, and then run `ipython` via `ipython whatever.py`.

You can also run Python code by [modifying your `~/.ipython/ipy_user_conf.py`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.2/html/config/customization.html#ipy-user-conf-py):

> There should be a simple template `ipy_user_conf.py` file in your `~/.ipython` directory. It is a plain python module that is imported during IPython startup, so you can do pretty much what you want there - import modules, configure extensions, change options, define magic commands, put variables and functions in the IPython namespace, etc. You use the IPython extension api object, acquired by `IPython.ipapi.get()` and documented in the "IPython extension API" chapter, to interact with IPython.

You can also place [a file called `ipythonrc`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.2/html/config/customization.html#the-ipythonrc-approach) in your current working directory:

> As we've already mentioned, IPython reads a configuration file which can be specified at the command line (`-rcfile`) or which by default is assumed to be called `ipythonrc`. Such a file is looked for in the current directory where IPython is started and then in your `IPYTHONDIR`, which allows you to have local configuration files for specific projects. In this section we will call these types of configuration files simply `rcfiles` (short for resource configuration file).
>
> **execute** : give any single-line python code to be executed.
>
> **execfile** : execute the python file given with an `execfile(filename)` command. Username expansion is performed on the given names. So if you need any amount of extra fancy customization that won't fit in any of the above 'canned' options, you can just put it in a separate python file and execute it.